# Adding a button to a Windows Form App in Visual Studios 2010

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

so I'm creating an app for an internal tool and am trying to transfer the functionality of a check box on one of the forms to a button. Using the designer interface, what would be the best way of doing this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Appearance Property of CheckBox itself. I get this from rwiti answer which reminds me CheckBox too has `Appearance` property.

```
chk.Appearance = Appearance.Button;
```

You're done..

Comment: Note that although this makes it *look* like a button, it still *works* like a checkbox. That can be rather confusing.

Comment: @CodyGray yes but question says it is gonna be used in `Internal tool` so that won't be a problem i think. and even requirement is also the same right?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `RadioButton` and do this

```
this.radioButton1.Appearance = System.Windows.Forms.Appearance.Button;
```

Comment: I think you missed CheckBox itself have this property.